# Disabled copy and paste after adding wordcount plugin of Ckeditor

Tags: notifications, ckeditor, word-count

I am using **wordcount** plugin of **ckeditor** for word count. As requirment of this plugin i added plugin '**notification**'. My problem is this after adding notification plugin **copy and paste via keypress got disabled**. I am getting following error in my console: 
NOTE : Word Counts are displaying correctly.

> Uncaught TypeError: CKEDITOR.tools.getUniqueId is not a function
>   Notification @ plugin.js?t=E4KA:121 (anonymous function) @
>   plugin.js?t=E4KA:360 i @ ckeditor.js:10
>   CKEDITOR.event.CKEDITOR.event.fire @ ckeditor.js:12
>   CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire @ ckeditor.js:13 f @
>   ckeditor.js:594 (anonymous function) @ ckeditor.js:599 (anonymous
>   function) @ ckeditor.js:598

My code is as follows for adding word count and other plugin:

```
CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'toolbar';
CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'htmlwriter';
CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'notification';
CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'wordcount';
CKEDITOR.config.wordcount = {
        showParagraphs: true,
        showWordCount: true,
        countSpacesAsChars: false,
        countHTML: false,
        maxWordCount: 10
};
```

Is there anything that i am doing wrong here?
Please help me out. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. It seems that the Notification plugin doesn't work with CKEditor versions lower than 4.5. So you need to upgrade the CKEditor. You can build again the CKEditor package on the website and add to your previous build-config new plugins that you need now - wordcount and notification.

Answer (score 1):

Firsly, convert this`

```
CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'toolbar';
CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'htmlwriter';
CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'notification';
CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'wordcount';
```

to this`

```
CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'toolbar,htmlwriter,notification,wordcount';
```

because you are overwriting the variable *CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins* value